# Spring и Vue.js папка static

Tags: java, spring-boot

Смотрю ролики про спринг. По дефолту html файл делался в папке ресурсы-темплейтс. Смотрю видео про spring c Vue. Там папку делают статик, Имеет ли значение название папки? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOmcsf5IylI&list=PLU2ftbIeotGqSTOVNjT4L3Yfy8jatCdhm

Answer (score 0):

А зачем тебе названия папок. Я тебе советую создать отдельный модуль в своем сборщике, и в этот модуль залить свои `Vue.js` файлы.

Отвечая на твой вопрос, можно сказать, что ДА, важно файлы `.js`, `.css`, `.html` в каталог по пути(если это `Gradle`) ***resources/templates/static***.
При этом необходимо в `Spring Security` конфигах настроить данный путь, а так же в конфигах `MVC` указать пути:

1. MVC:

```java
 /**
     * Данный метод помогает Spring обнаруживать пути к файлам
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/templates/");
    }
```

2. Spring Security Configs:

```java
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http

                .cors().disable().csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                // Раздаем статику
                .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
// .......... остальной код настроек
}
```